# Filter dataframe but only in rows that meet certain conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my first question asked, I apologize if I am not clear.

I have a dataframe with 2 cols: city and age. I would like to filter in some age range, but only in certain cities.

```
x <- tibble(city = c("LA","LA","LA","NY","NY","NY"), age = c(10,20,30,15,25,35))
```

I would like to retain all values in which `city == "LA"`, but when `city == "NY"`, only those with `age >20`

Can I do it with `dplyr::filter`??

Comment: `filter(x, city != "NY" | age > 20)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `|` condition with `&` i.e. create the logical condition to return TRUE when city is "LA" or (`|`) when both conditions are TRUE i.e. `city` value is "NY" and (`&`) `age` is greater than 20

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
   filter(city != "NY"|(city == "NY" & age > 20))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  city    age
  <chr> <dbl>
1 LA       10
2 LA       20
3 LA       30
4 NY       25
5 NY       35
```

---

Or another option is to have a single expression and negate (`!`)

```
x %>% 
    filter(!(city == "NY" & age <= 20))
```

---

In `base R`, change the `filter` to `subset`

```
subset(x, city != "NY"|(city == "NY" & age > 20))
```

Comment: Thanks! There is a way to automatize (if there are more cities like LA, in this example)?

Comment: @uow use the second option i.e. `x %>% filter(!(city == "NY" & age <= 20))`

Answer (score 1):

According to your condition, this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
    filter(city == "LA" | city == "NY" & age > 20)
```

output

```
city    age
  <chr> <dbl>
1 LA       10
2 LA       20
3 LA       30
4 NY       25
5 NY       35
```